# qt5 gujarati font not working in ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, fonts, qt5

Earlier versions of qt (4.8) supported gujarati fonts fully.  We were able to use gujarati fonts in our application based on qt 4.8 in ubuntu as well as windows. Currently we are trying to transition to qt5.  But we have been unable to display gujarati fonts in ubuntu while it is successfully displayed in windows.